# What is a sustainable way of stacking?

Tags: tetris

In modern Tetris, there is a system of [piece randomization](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Generator) that takes a bag of seven pieces, and takes them out of a bag so that there is an even frequency of each piece. How can I use this fact to stack so that the playing field is always level, and it repeats itself indefinitely?

Obviously, this is not a good way of stacking in Tetris Battle, because it is neither offensive nor defensive, but it is a good way to keep the stack low.

Answer (score -1):

With enough piece previews, and hold, it is possible to play forever using some loops, though they do not always keep the stack low, and with higher gravity/speed settings aren't always possible.

The techniques are well detailed in this [Playing forever](http://harddrop.com/wiki/Playing_forever) article, so I won't repeat them.

Comment: 6/3 stacking doest guarantee a complete loop, and it doesn't use a certain algorithm either, which is not "sustainable"

Comment: It's absolutely sustainable, most forms are using the modern piece randomization used in Tetris games called the Random Generator. The loop detailed in the playing forever link, which is absolutely sustainable, not sure why you downvoted me for that... Almost any type of stacking with the Random Generator is sustainable.

Comment: It doesn't follow an algorithm, so it's not sustainable...

Comment: Doesn't matter, I still provide a method with an algorithm that is literally called playing forever, and you still downvote my answer... This site is great!